# How to use single input box two value?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

in my Previous i have two  separate input box % and $ value  looks like this  my code :

```
<tr>
    <td>Down payment $</td>
    <td>
        <input name="downpaymentpc" id="downpaymentpc" type="text" size="8" maxlength="8" onChange="javascript:downPaymentPcChanged(true);" value="<?php echo $min_fha_down_payment;?>" />%</td>
    <td colspan="2">Or $
        <input name="downpaymentamt" id="downpaymentamt" type="text" size="8" maxlength="8" onChange="javascript:downPaymentAmountChanged(true);" />
    </td>
</tr>
```

this my old code  its have two separate  input fields its Working well.after that i changed in my new design . i have set single input fields i have to set % and $ image on click change  code Looks like

```
<div class="col-md-2 padding-Zero">
    <input name="downpaymentpc" id="downpaymentpc" type="text" class="txt" size="8" maxlength="8" onChange="javascript:downPaymentPcChanged(true);" value="<?php echo $min_fha_down_payment;?>" />
</div>

<div class="col-md-1 padding-lft">
    <img src="Content/Images/percent.png" onclick="changeColor(event,this.src)" style="cursor:pointer" />
</div>
```

i have no idea about it how to set another value in single input fields when i change image % to $ ? any idea about ? please help me ?Really stuck it?

< --NEW -->

In this code don't have id   its have only name

```
<td>Monthly MIP </td>
        <td>
          <input name="monthlymippc" type="text" size="8" maxlength="8" onChange="javascript:monthlyMIPPcChanged(true)" />
        %</td>
        <td>Or $

          <input name="monthlymipamt" type="text" size="8" maxlength="8" onChange="javascript:monthlyMIPAmountChanged(true)"/>
          </td>
```

My script:

i added extra id in code   and i have create this script its not Working..

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $(".changeImgvalue").click(functon(){
         var type=$(this).attr("type");
         if(type == 'per'){
             $(this).attr({
                 "type":"amount",
                 "src":"content/Images/percent.png"
             });
             $("#monthlymippc").attr("onchange","javascript:monthlyMIPPcChanged(true);");
         } else if(type == 'amount'){
              $(this).attr({
                  "type" :"per";
                  "src":"content/Images/RedDoller.png"
              })
              $("#monthlymipamt").attr("onchange",onChange="javascript:monthlyMIPAmountChanged(true)")
         }
     })
})
```

any error in my code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HTML:**

```
<img src="Content/Images/percent.png" type="per" class="changeImg" style="cursor:pointer"/>
```

**Jquery:**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".changeImg").click(function () {
        var type = $(this).attr("type");
        if (type == 'per') {
            $(this).attr({
                "type": "amount",
                "src": "Content/Images/dollar.png"
            });
            $("#downpaymentpc").attr("onchange", "downPaymentAmountChanged(true);");

        } else if (type == 'amount') {
            $(this).attr({
                "type": "per",
                "src": "Content/Images/percent.png"
            });
            $("#downpaymentpc").attr("onchange", "downPaymentPcChanged(true);");
        }
    });
});
```

**HTML:**

```
<img src="Content/Images/percent.png" type="per" class="changeImg" style="cursor:pointer"/>
```

**Jquery:**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".changeImg").click(function () {
        var type = $(this).attr("type");
        if (type == 'per') {
            $(this).attr({
                "type": "amount",
                "src": "Content/Images/dollar.png"
            });

        } else if (type == 'amount') {
            $(this).attr({
                "type": "per",
                "src": "Content/Images/percent.png"
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: how to assign another value in input fields. i have set the code  onclick change image . but  now in my code i have put single value.   another value  how i will put in input fields

Comment: its Working .but when i change to  % to $ working.after that revert that change to $ to % not Working after  refresh the page after only Working

Comment: Sorry, not following you. Can you update your issue in your question?

Comment: You said you will have single input and in your update, you are having 2 inputs ?

Comment: now i moved new part in my task  Monthly MIP  have two input fields   my new design on input fields. same as my previous question . that code have id. this code don't have id have only name

Comment: As you have 2 input fields, you don't have to change javascript functions. You just need to change the image of clicked right?

Comment: if click   image % image showing  % value  and click $  image showing $ value @disha Sorry i give so much trouble  to u sorry it.  i am new in javascript and jquery

Comment: @Stackmail, I am here to help you no worries, check my updated code and tell me if it's working?

Comment: I have updated it to my answer.. see last HTML and jquery sections

Comment: i  have two  number from database % value is 3.5  and $ value  something  . but % value is default .   update  r code image only change value not changed .

Comment: when image is changed, `type` attribute of `<img>` will also be changed, did you see that?

Comment: ok @Disha .. one doubt    No need to assign    downPaymentAmountChanged(true)     and downPaymentPcChanged(true)  in script ?